# How to manage slightly different versions of the same application on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

I have a Rails 4.2 application that is tailor-made for a specific industry and now I have to upload the same app, but for a new client from a different industry. Given this, I need to do some slightly changes in the database and code (90% of the code should remain the same). What is the best approach to have different versions of the same app? Should I use Rails plugins? I don't want to have two completely separate application because I will be doing maintenance twice almost all the time and having one big app will make it too complicated (and also I need two different database structures)

Please let me know what is the best option.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible solutions include creating a Rails Engine, using dependency injection, or making your application more extensible than it normally would be. The Engine approach is often the most straight-forward, where your core application is the foundation you build the two other specialized ones on.

Comment: @tadman´s advice is spot on. I'm voting to close this though since the question is primarily opinion based as you are asking for the best option which is a matter of opinion. It also really depends on the case. The best solution may be to actually create several engines which are modular components that can be integrated into your apps.